# Increase Version number if Travis at github was successful

Tags: python, github, versioning, travis-ci

I wrote a simple [script](https://github.com/guettli/compare-with-remote) in Python.

Now I would like travis to check my code. After travis was successful, the version number should get increased.

Up to now my script has no version number yet. I can store it anywhere where it makes sense for the auto-increment workflow.

How to do this for Python code?

## Update

It works now:

1. run tests
2. bumpversion
3. push tag to master

Unfortunately travis does not support "after-all". This means if I want to run the tests for several Python versions, I have no way to bumpversion after the tests of all python versions were successful.

In my case I will check on Python2.7 only until travis resolved this issue: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/929

Here is my simple script: https://github.com/guettli/compare-with-remote

## Solved :-)

It works now:

1. Developer pushes to github
2. Travis-CI runs
3. If all tests are successful bumpversion increases the version
4. The new version in setup.py get's pushed to the github repo
5. A new release of the python package gets uploaded to pypi with the tool `twine`.

I explain the way I do CI with github, travis and pypi here: https://github.com/guettli/github-travis-bumpversion-pypi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you accept having extra commit for your versioning, you could add this script in `continuous_integration/increment_version.py`

```
import os
import pkg_resources


if __name__ == "__main__":
    version = pkg_resources.get_distribution("compare_with_remote").version
    split_version = version.split('.')
    try:
        split_version[-1] = str(int(split_version[-1]) + 1)
    except ValueError:
        # do something about the letters in the last field of version
        pass
    new_version = '.'.join(split_version)
    os.system("sed -i \"s/version='[0-9.]\+'/version='{}'/\" setup.py"
              .format(new_version))
    os.system("git add -u")
    os.system("git commit -m '[ci skip] Increase version to {}'"
              .format(new_version))
    os.system("git push")
```

And change your `.travis.yml` to

```
after_success:
  - python continuous_integration/increment_version.py
```

I am not sure about how to make the `git push` part work as it need some testing with the repo rights but I assume that you could probably setup something to allow travis to push in your repo. you could look into that [post](https://gist.github.com/domenic/ec8b0fc8ab45f39403dd) for instance.

Also note that I used `python` to perform the `git` operations but they can be added as extra line  in the `after_success` field:

```
after_success:
  - python continuous_integration/increment_version.py
  - git add -u
  - git commit -m "[ci skip] version changed"
  - git push
```

I just find it convenient to put the version number in the commit msg.

Also, it is very important to add [[ci skip]](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Skipping-a-build) in the commit message to avoid infinite increment. Maybe it would be safer to trigger the version change on a specific commit msg tag.

Comment: thank you for the hint "infinite increment". Does travis look at the commit messages and detect "ci skip"?

Comment: Yes the [skip ci] tag is detected by default with Travis.

Answer (score 4):

Not Python-specific, but [this tutorial](http://phdesign.com.au/programming/auto-increment-project-version-from-travis/) explains auto-incrementing version numbers by adding `.travis.yaml` entries which update git tags with each successful build. It seems like a good balance between manual and auto-versioning.

While the tutorial does use npm's `package.json` for the initial version-check, you could implement a simple equivalent (in Python or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that,

- only commits with successful Travis CI builds get merged into the master branch (e.g. using Pull Requests)
- the package is always installed with pip from a git repo using, for instance,

  ```
  pip install git+https://github.com/user/package.git
  ```

For auto-incrementing version number, one could simply define the version as the number of commits in the master branch. This can be done with the following lines in **setup.py**,

```
minor_version = check_output(['git', 'rev-list',
                              '--count', 'master']).decode('latin-1').strip()

setup(version='0.{}'.format(minor_version), ...)
```

Comment: In my case the master branch is for development. It can contain bugs.